# How to train a spacy model by using streaming data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, stream, spacy

I have created a spacy model. But I need to retrain it until it reaches it maximum level. I need to train this model and retrain the model using the streaming data. I have seen that we can train some machine learning model using stream data. Is it possible to do the same to NLP models?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom corpus reader for your data (https://spacy.io/api/top-level#corpus-readers) and use the setting `max_epochs = -1` to indicate that the data should be streamed:

```ini
[training]
max_epochs = -1
```

Depending on the type of component and the data, you may need to additionally initialize the labels for the component in the `[initialize]` block. If you're not streaming, the labels are automatically initialized from the full training corpus, but you can use `spacy init labels` to generate the labels based on a subset of the data instead and initialize them separately.

More details: https://spacy.io/usage/v3-1#streaming-corpora